# Finding max(date) efficiently in pyspark without groupby or calling collect()

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

1) I need to use `date_diff()` in my code to find the difference between the `Date` column and `Max(Date)`

What I am using right now

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
max_date = df.select(F.max(df['date'])).collect()[0][0]
df = df.withColumn('period_difference', F.datediff(F.lit(max_date), df['date']))
```

It is taking around 6 minutes to finish. Is there a better efficient way to do it?

2) Is there a way I can get the difference returned by `date_diff()` in months? In pandas you can use :

```
import numpy as np
df['period_difference'] = ((max(df['date']) - df['date']) / np.timedelta64(1, 'M'))
```

I am just trying to replicate the above line of code in pandas to pyspark.

Comment: This is exactly how I am doing it in my use case as well, and can't think of anything that will be more efficient.

Comment: Understood @Gopala

Answer (score 0):

You can delay delay the execution

```
max_date = df.select(F.max(df['date']).alias("max_date"))    
df.crossJoin(max_date).withColumn(
   'period_difference', F.datediff(F.col('max_date'), F.col('date')
)
```

but you cannot avoid the problem in general. Finding maximum value on unsorted data structure which doesn't support indexing data will always require full data scan.